# Alarm Manager Notification Setting Cookies

Tags: java, android, cookies, notifications, alarmmanager

I am having some problem when trying to prompt notification based on the timing set by Alarm Manager in Android.

So what I am trying to do is a budget setting application. If the monthly expenses exceed the budget, it will prompt notification. In order to keep the question short, I will just post the part where I interact with Alarm Manager:

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BudgetAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi = null;
        if (bm.getReminderNotify().equals("Y")
                && percentage >= 90) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
            notificationCount = notificationCount + 1;

            // Set request flag to 1 so that the same pending intent in broadcastReceiver
            notificationIntent.putExtra("NotifyCount", notificationCount);
            pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

What I am trying to do here is to check if the expenses exceed the budget. And inside the BudgetAlarm class, I am prompting the notification:

```
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Notification notification;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
            new Intent(), 0);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification",
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Budget Reminder",
            "Your monthly expenses nearly exceed the budget!",
            contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount")
                    .toString()), notification);
}
```

My problem now is it does set and trigger the alarm manager every day. But let's say today I did not run the apps, it does prompt me a notification to notify me. But after a while, I launch the app, then it prompt me again.

I wonder is there any way to set the notification to just notify once per day regardless of how many times I launch the apps. I was actually thinking of something like cookies or shared preference.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
public class BudgetAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Notification notification;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    saveDay(context);
    if (sameDay(context) == false) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
                new Intent(), 0);
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Budget Reminder",
                "Your monthly expenses nearly exceed the budget!",
                contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(
                Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("NotifyCount")
                        .toString()), notification);
        saveDay(context);
    }
}

private boolean sameDay(Context context) {
    boolean isSameDay = false;
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PrefKey",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date today = cal.getTime();
    String day = format.format(today);

    String savedDate = pref.getString("SaveDateKey", "NONE");

    if (savedDate.equals(day)) {
        isSameDay = true;
    } else {
        isSameDay = false;
    }
    return isSameDay;
}

private void saveDay(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PrefKey",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date today = cal.getTime();
    String day = format.format(today);
    editor.putString("SaveDateKey", day);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: I think the question is, why is Your AlarmManager fireing again when You opened Your App. So I guess the manager will startet every time You starting the App, is that what You wanted?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Yeah I am having that problem. I am actually wanted it to prompt the notification once per day regardless of the times I opened the apps if the expense exceed the budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You are on the right way with shared preferences. This could be a scenario in Your app: make a method to know if the same day is equal, if not, save the date when You start the app:

```
  private boolean sameDay(){

  boolean isSameDay = false;
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVAT);

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 Date today = cal.getTime();
 String day = format.format(today);

 String savedDate = pref.getString(YOUR_SAVED_DATE_KEY,"NONE");

 if(savedDate.equals(day){
    isSameDay=true;
 }else{
    isSameDay=false;
  } 
    return isSameDay;
}
```

And to save the current day:

```
private void saveDay(){

  SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVAT);


 Editor editor = pref.edit();

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 Date today = cal.getTime();
 String day = format.format(today);

 editor.putString(YOUR_SAVED_DATE_KEY,day);
 editor.commit();
 }
```

And then You just handling this inside Your onReceive():

```
 if(sameDay==true){
    //don´t notify

 }else{
  //notify and save the day
  saveDay();
 }
```

Comment: But it's throwing me null pointer exception at the shared preference line in sameDay(). Can you please help me check if I am doing wrongly from my edited portion?

Comment: mmm.. a nullPOinterException...but Your code looks good. Can You post the logcat, maybe I can then see more..

Comment: ahh forget it, You have not initialized Your context in the BroadcastReceiver. And it´s better to not use equal named objekts. Just do Context mContext; and then in onReceive mContext = context;

Comment: I've modified my code but it does not prompt notification at all.

Comment: because You are calling saveDay() directly in onReceive(). Then the day is saved and is equal if You call sameDay after this. Just delete the first saveDay();

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, the null pointer exception is because of the context. Thanks! It works!!!